# How to trace exact issue from Firebase Crashlytics log in React Native App?

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have a React Native app with Firebase crashlytics integrated. I am forcefully crashing the app by calling function which does not exist. (this.test()).

I am getting logs in crashlytics, but looking at that logs I am not able to track the exact issue location.
Logs are quite generic and which is not helping me to pinpoint the issue.

Is there any way to get more info on that issue from logs? or anything I need to do so that I can get the issue location? if we are getting an issue in the inded.js file can we trace back the exact js file in app which is causing the issue.

[image]

Please help me with this information. Than you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here - it sounds like you'd benefit from [Crashlytics custom logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#add-logs). This tool allows you to log any messages you want that get appended to the Crashlytics crash report that gets sent up to the console. I'm not sure how the React Native wrapper for Firebase Crashlytics works or if it allows you to do this, but according to the [React Native Firebase reference doc](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/crashlytics#log) you should be able to.

With this tool, you could call `log` in your code whenever you want to record information about the session, the user, or whatever's happening with code that you're executing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

We can use crashlytics logs to see on which screen our crash occured.It is availabe near the stacktrace section in the Logs tab. There is a property named `firebase_screen` which you can use to see which screen the user was on when the app crashed.
https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:720/format:webp/1*63O7u1M6eWUfyQ9Humafww.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).